# Connecting a Looper to a Guitar Multieffects Pedal

Tags: guitar, guitar-effects, production, looping

I want to practice guitar silently via headphones using a looper (Boss RC-30) and a multieffects pedal (Im considering the Boss GT-100).
The Multieffect board has an fx loop (send/return). I'm thinking of the four-cable-method to accomplish this.

1. Is it possible to connect the looper to the considered multieffexts
   board via send/return in such a fashion that not the looper's
   playback will be affected by the effect settings, only the input?
   Will the recording sound 'as is', e.g. can I record a clean part and
   then overdub a distorted lead sound without colouring the clean
   sound?
2. Are both the looper's playback and the live guitar sound
   audible via headphones plugged in to the GT-100?

The  [GT-100 manual](https://static.roland.com/assets/media/pdf/GT-100_e03_W.pdf) (p. 29) describes three send/return modes, but how does that refer to my concern?

Comment: There's no send/return on my RC-30s. There's 2 in and 2 out, for stereo use.

Comment: You're right, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Try using the second channel on the looper to go - fx out> RC  2nd in, RC 2nd out > fx other channel in, or > fx return. Just a wild card.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I can think of, which is what I used to do in the same situation, would be to just set it up as such: guitar -> multi fx -> looper -> headphones. Ultimately any output from the looper will include all of the loops without isolating the input track (if there's no fx send/return), so using an output wouldn't accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: Trouble is, there's no headphone socket on the looper.

Comment: I could have sworn there was a headphone out on there... I have one but it's a little older, so I guess I'll have to double check that.

Comment: With 'phones out', the problem's solved!

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the GT100 or GT1000 you have to activate the send and return in your effects chain and moving it to the final, just before your outputs (headphone, amps or speaker). Then yo connect the from send GT100 to input of looper and output of looper to return of gt100. You can do this stereo or mono depending if you use one or both send and return options.

I used this method to connect my GT1000 with RC-10r looper using the headphone output of GT1000.